# Migration file don't change Site name and domain

Tags: django, migration, sites, django-sites

I have this migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site as DjangoSite


def change_django_site(apps, schema_editor):
    site = DjangoSite.objects.get(id=1)
    site.delete()

    DjangoSite.objects.get_or_create(id=1, domain='www.xprende.com', name='XPrende')


def create_homepage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    Page = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Page')
    Site = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Site')
    HomePage = apps.get_model('home.HomePage')

    # Delete the default homepage
    # If migration is run multiple times, it may have already been deleted
    Page.objects.filter(id=2).delete()

    # Create content type for homepage model
    homepage_content_type, __ = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
        model='homepage', app_label='home')

    # Create a new homepage
    homepage = HomePage.objects.create(
        title="Home",
        draft_title="Home",
        slug='home',
        content_type=homepage_content_type,
        path='00010001',
        depth=2,
        numchild=0,
        url_path='/home/',
    )

    # Create a site with the new homepage set as the root
    Site.objects.create(
        hostname='www.xprende.com', site_name='XPrende', root_page=homepage, is_default_site=True
    )


def remove_homepage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    HomePage = apps.get_model('home.HomePage')

    # Delete the default homepage
    # Page and Site objects CASCADE
    HomePage.objects.filter(slug='home', depth=2).delete()

    # Delete content type for homepage model
    ContentType.objects.filter(model='homepage', app_label='home').delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('home', '0001_initial'),
        ('sites', '0002_alter_domain_unique'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            create_homepage,
            remove_homepage,
            change_django_site,
        ),
    ]
```

As you can see i made a function that have to change the `django` site name and domain. But it doesn't do it, after apply the migrations i get the same default values:

```
In [3]: DjangoSite.objects.get(id=1)
Out[3]: <Site: example.com>

In [4]: DjangoSite.objects.get(id=1).name
Out[4]: 'example.com'

In [5]: DjangoSite.objects.get(id=1).domain
Out[5]: 'example.com'

In [6]: DjangoSite.objects.all()
Out[6]: <QuerySet [<Site: example.com>]>
```

I can't understand why, i put the `sites` migrations as dependencie of this migration file but still it doesn't works.

Can anyone explain me why i have this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you run the migration and that it runs without errors? Could you maybe remove the `change_django_site` migration, run again and check that `DjangoSites.objects.count()` equals to 0.

Comment: Have you added this functions to `Migration.operations` list?

Comment: @zvadym did you see the code? Yes, i did, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @SalahAdDin sorry, I haven't noticed scroll..

Comment: Stop, why `migrations.RunPython` has three arguments? `RunPython(code, reverse_code=None, atomic=None, hints=None, elidable=False)`. So, `change_django_site` assigned to `atomic`

Comment: @sinned I haven't any error.

Comment: @zvadym I have to open a new `RunPython` command for thes operation?

Comment: @SalahAdDin yes!

Comment: Yes, i do it and i have a new error:`__fake__.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158978/discussion-between-zvadym-and-salahaddin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `change_django_site` as separate operation:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('home', '0001_initial'),
        ('sites', '0002_alter_domain_unique'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(change_django_site, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
        migrations.RunPython(create_homepage, reverse_code=remove_homepage),
    ]
```

and `change_django_site` must be

```
def change_django_site(apps, schema_editor): 
    DjangoSite = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site') 
    site = DjangoSite.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    site.domain='www.xprende.com'
    site.name='XPrende'
    site.save()
```

Comment: Please add this change to my function:
```
def change_django_site(apps, schema_editor):
    DjangoSite = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site')

    DjangoSite.objects.get_or_create(id=1, domain='www.xprende.com', name='XPrende')
```